# Self-join in Oracle SQL - selecting rows based on 1 same column and 1 different column

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, self-join

It may not be a self-join I need, but I'm having difficulty with this problem and I hope someone can help me.

Sample Data:

```
Row   Code   ReservationID   ClientID EmployeeID
1     T            123          7777     John 
2     T            456          2020     John
3     P            456          2020     John
4     P            999          3100     Steve
5     P            876          3100     Steve
6     T            333          2424     John
7     P            333          2424     Lynda
```

Desired output:

```
Row   Code   ReservationID   ClientID EmployeeID
2     T            456          2020     John
3     P            456          2020     John
6     T            333          2424     John
7     P            333          2424     Lynda
```

I'm looking for a query that will only return Rows 2, 3, 6, and 7.

The selection criteria is when there is a row with Code = T and another row with Code = P but for the same Reservation ID and CLientID.  The EmployeeID may be the same or different (I want to return the EmployeeID in the results but not use it in the select criteria).

Reading forums I think I need a self-join (which I don't know how to do).  Any help you can offer would really be appreciated!  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the simplest solution is:

```
select distinct t1.*
  from my_table t1
  join my_table t2 on t1.reservationid = t2.reservationid
  where t1.code = 'T' and t2.code = 'P'
     or t1.code = 'P' and t2.code = 'T';
```

Comment: It runs forever and fails.  What if there are more columns in the table then I mentioned?  Do I have to include every column in the table in the join?

Comment: It's failing due to limitations in my corporate technical environment and the size of the source data table, but the query you suggested is good.  Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

One method uses `exists`:

```
select t.*
from t
where (t.code = 'T' and exists (select 1 from t t2 where t2.reservationId = t.reservationId and t2.clientId = t.clientId and t2.code = 'P'
                               )
      ) or
      (t.code = 'P' and exists (select 1 from t t2 where t2.reservationId = t.reservationId and t2.clientId = t.clientId and t2.code = 'T'
                               )
      );
```

For performance, you want an index on `(reservationId, clientId, code)`.

Comment: Thank you!  I'm testing this right now, but it's taking a really long time to run.  Will report back shortly...

Comment: It runs forever and fails.  What if there are more columns in the table then I mentioned?  Do I have to include every column in the table in the sub-selects?

Comment: It's failing due to limitations in my corporate technical environment and the size of the source data table, but the query you suggested is good. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I think a more convenient way would be to use the [`row_number`](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions170.htm) window function. You'd give a row number for every row within the same `ReservationID` and `ClientID` in a descending order of `Code`, and then filter according to this numbering:

```
SELECT Row, Code, ReservationID, ClientID, EmployeeID
FROM   (SELECT Row, Code, ReservationID, ClientID, EmployeeID,
               ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ReservationID, ClientID
                                  ORDER BY Code DESC) AS rn
        FROM   mytable) t
WHERE  rn = 1
```